# Strange "Service Unavailable Error 500" when migrating a Drupal website from server to local ubuntu 16.04 machine

Tags: php, apache, drupal, localhost

Iv'e recently tried to install my website locally, on my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop.
After copying the right files, giving the right permissions, and finally uploading the sql dump to the database, I keep getting "Error 500" on the website's root.

Examining the network tab, nothing special comes up.
Checking apache error/access logs - nothing at all (error reporting is on ufcourse).

First thing I did was to remove the .htaccess file, but it did'nt help.
I also tried to disable all modules but nothing.

Is there any mismatch between Ubuntu 16.04 and Drupal?
I run PHP5.6, and apache2.

Has someone encountered something similiar before?

Comment: There is no reason Ubuntu 16.04 can't run Drupal 7 or 8 (older Drupals might struggle with modern PHP but they aren't supported for a reason). If you can't get anything, you might try a static file and eliminate Drupal/PHP from the equation and determine which later is giving you headaches.  Without more details on the setup it's hard to give any direct suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to identify just from your words, but you try next actions and bring results here, so will be more clear what is wrong:

1) please check if you have .htaccess file in your site root folder, if not or modified - try with default for your drupal version, just doenload from drupal.org.

2) Please try to open text file from same folder, like local.site/README.txt - if you have not modified drupal version you should have this file in the root site folder. 
If it works correctly and you can see Drupal readme

3) remove settings.php and try to open site, do you see install drupal screen?

4) then just put this lines to the index.php under

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

and try to open any page

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have MySQL PDO extension `php_pdo_mysql.dll`  installed and enabled.

To install the extension for PHP 7.0:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

To enable the extension:

1. go to `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`
2. locate line `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` and remove semicolon (`;`) in the start of the line, if present. In case semicolon is absent in the start of the line, it means extension is already enabled.

Hope it helps.